# How to execute python inside blend file from command line

Tags: python, rendering, command-line

I'll explain the numbering of what I did.

1. I created a text file called lowRes inside the blend file as shown in the attached image.
   [image]
2. And I noticed that when I click Run Script in Blender run with GUI, the resolution of all scenes is changed to 128x72.
3. Then undo by pressing Ctrl + Z, set it to 1920x1080 resolution, and save the file.
4. And I did the Command Line Rendering using the code below.

```
blender -b "my.blend" ^
-P lowRes.py ^
-S "scene 01" ^
-o "//output\##" -F PNG -f 3 ^
-S "scene 02" ^
-o "//output\##" -F PNG -f 5
```

good.
`03.png` and `05.png` were generated as expected.
But the resolution is 1920x1080, not 128x72.
The python code doesn't seem to be running.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW This works as expected for me.  The `-P` is for an external python script. If so: make sure your script is saved in same folder as CLI.  Passing a wrong name for script it fails silently and renders images with default size.  If the script is a text block in blend then   `blender -b --python-text "lowRes"`

Comment: @batFINGER amazing! That works for me!
`--python-text` was listed in the official manual but I haven't looked into it closely.
I have one last thing I want to know.
As far as I know, if you don't have a textblock or external python file, you can run python code with `--python-expr`.
But I failed to execute lowRes code using `--python-expr`.
I am using Notepad.
How can I write code that works correctly?

Comment: An example of using expression `blender -b --python-expr "import bpy; print(bpy.data.scenes[:])"`  Personally wouldn't do it. Would use the external script. (Save from notepad with a .py extension)

Comment: @batFINGER Am I misunderstanding expression?
I expected to include the code for `scene.render.resolution_x` and `scene.render.resolution_y` after `--python-expr`.
However, from the example you wrote, it seems that `--python-expr` doesn't work alone.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by working alone?  Have to somehow put the whole script into a single line expression.  Again: I  Wouldn't use that option.

Comment: @batFINGER Thank you for your time. I understood.